Call to a member function prepare() on null al intentar cambiar de base de datos MYSQL
Estoy intentando hacer que el usuario pueda seleccionar una de las bases de datos que ya hay mediante un select en tiempo real y que se cambie para la aplicación, pero cada vez que lo intento sale el error.
Esto es lo que tengo de código:

public function changeDatabase(Request $request)
    {
        $newDbName = $request->input('database');

        // Verificar si la base de datos existe
        $databaseExists = DB::select('SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = ?', [$newDbName]);

        if (empty($databaseExists)) {
            return back()->with('error', "La base de datos $newDbName no existe.");
        }

        // Cambiar la configuración de la base de datos en runtime
        Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $newDbName);
        DB::purge('mysql');


        DB::reconnect('mysql');

        // Probar la conexión a la nueva base de datos
        try {
            DB::connection()->getPdo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return back()->with('error', 'No se pudo conectar a la nueva base de datos: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        // Regenerar la sesión para evitar problemas
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return back()->with('success', "Base de datos cambiada a $newDbName");
    }

    public function showChangeDatabaseForm()
    {
        // Obtener todas las bases de datos que contienen "cupo"
        $databases = DB::select("SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'cupo%'");
        $databaseNames = array_map(function ($db) {
            return $db->{"Database (cupo%)"};
        }, $databases);

        return view('change-database', ['databases' => $databaseNames]);
    }

La aplicación está hecha en Laravel 11 y esta es una parte muy importante del proyecto.

¿En qué línea aparece el error de prepare()?

El error dice que falla la llamada a prepare() y tu código no muestra ninguna llamada a prepare() ¿Estás seguro/a que este es el fragmento relevante del código? ¿cuál es la línea donde salta el error?

El error salta en la línea 17 del archivo public/index.php, cuando intento hacer dd() para ver cuándo ocurre el error siempre salta después del return back()

Recuerda siempre mostrar el código relevante en la pregunta. El punto de preguntar en qué línea aparece el error es para que muestres el error en la pregunta misma. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles, y lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.
